# LWC radio buttons not selectable

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to create a simple LWC which renders five horizonal radio buttons (and potentially a sixth for N/A based on an input parameter.) They render fine but are unresponsive to clicks. What am I doing wrong?

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import {FlowAttributeChangeEvent} from 'lightning/flowSupport';

export default class LikertRadioButtons extends LightningElement {

@api selectedValue;
@api includeNA;
@api fieldName;
@api labelLow;
@api labelHigh;
@track selectedValue;
@track includeNA;
@track fieldName;
@track labelLow;

connectedCallback(){
    
    if(this.selectedValue){
        var rad_ele = this.template.querySelectorAll(fieldName);
        for (var i = 0; i < rad_ele.length; ++i) {
            if(rad_ele[i].value == this.selectedValue){rad_ele[i].checked = true;}
        }
    }
}

// handle the selected value

handleSelected(e) {
    window.console.log('selected value ===> '+e.target.value);
    this.selectedValue = e.target.value;
    this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('selectedValue',selectedValue));
 }

}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <span class="slds-radio">
            <input name={fieldName} id="radio1" type="radio" value="1" onchange={handleSelected} />
            <label class="slds-radio__label" for="1">
                <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">1-{labelLow}</span>
            </label>
            
            <input name={fieldName} id="radio2" type="radio" value="2" onchange={handleSelected} />
            <label class="slds-radio__label" for="2">
                <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">2</span>                                
            </label>
            
            <input name={fieldName}  id="radio3" type="radio" value="3" onchange={handleSelected} />
            <label class="slds-radio__label" for="3">
                <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">3</span>
            </label>
            
            <input name={fieldName} id="radio4" type="radio" value="4" onchange={handleSelected} />
            <label class="slds-radio__label" for="4">
                <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">4</span>
            </label>
            
            <input name={fieldName} id="radio5" type="radio" value="5" onchange={handleSelected} />
            <label class="slds-radio__label" for="5">
                <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">5-{labelHigh}</span>
            </label>
        <template  lwc:if={includeNA}>
            &nbsp;| &nbsp;
            <input name={fieldName} id="radio0" type="radio" value="0" onchange={handleSelected} />
            <label class="slds-radio__label" for="0">
                <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">N/A</span>
            </label>
        </template>   
        </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some fundamental issues with the code but let's not get into that, to quick fix the existing code,

1. I put some value in the fieldName variable in the js file:

   @track fieldName='a';
2. in the HTML I put id attribute same as the value so HTML would look like this:

   ```
        <input name={fieldName} id="1" type="radio" value="1" onchange={handleSelected} />
        <label class="slds-radio__label" for="1">
            <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">1-{labelLow}</span>
        </label>

        <input name={fieldName} id="2" type="radio" value="2" onchange={handleSelected} />
        <label class="slds-radio__label" for="2">
            <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">2</span>                                
        </label>

        <input name={fieldName}  id="3" type="radio" value="3" onchange={handleSelected} />
        <label class="slds-radio__label" for="3">
            <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">3</span>
        </label>

        <input name={fieldName} id="4" type="radio" value="4" onchange={handleSelected} />
        <label class="slds-radio__label" for="4">
            <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">4</span>
        </label>

        <input name={fieldName} id="5" type="radio" value="5" onchange={handleSelected} />
        <label class="slds-radio__label" for="5">
            <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">5-{labelHigh}</span>
        </label>
        <template  lwc:if={includeNA}>
            &nbsp;| &nbsp;
            <input name={fieldName} id="0" type="radio" value="0" onchange={handleSelected} />
            <label class="slds-radio__label" for="0">
                <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">N/A</span>
            </label>
        </template>

    </span>
   ```

Comment: It works at first time of asking but when I go back from the next screen, it gives me an error: Something went wrong with the "Goal1Radios" screen component on the ".Engagement Report Screen Flow" flow. Contact your Salesforce admin about this error. fieldName is not defined

Comment: That problem was solved by using this.fieldName in the Javascript, but the button does not display a value when first visiting the screen (if the field has a value to begin with) not when returning to the screen.